# What is the best way to convert a string type to an int type as Industry standard?

Tags: c++, string, types

In C++, what is the best way to take input string and convert it to a number type. I was messing around with literal strings and was having a difficult time doing this, I am imagining that using a C String is easier? What is the best way for co-workers and fellow students to follow and make it easy and simple? Any thoughts?

***What is the industry standard on this? Using STOI*?**

Comment: Define "best". The problem with asking for the "best way", is that everyone's definition of "best" is different.

Comment: My preferred method is use of `boost::lexical_cast` if you have it.

Comment: No, the problem is that it's been answered 20,000 times before. Learn to research!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the following example:

```
std::string numberString = "125";
int number = std::stoi(numberString ,nullptr);
```

It can convert an `std::string` to `int`

Comment: Note: a compiler must have C++11 support to use stoi

Comment: If you're passing `nullptr` as the second parameter and not passing a third, you might as well leave it out and pass only `numberString`.